# How to read value of property depending on an argument

Tags: csv, reflection, properties, f#, arguments

How can I get the value of a property given a string argument.

I have a Object `CsvProvider.Row` which has attributes a,b,c.
I want to get the attribute value depending on property given as a string argument.
I tried something like this:

````
let getValue (tuple, name: string) =
    snd tuple |> Seq.averageBy (fun (y: CsvProvider<"s.csv">.Row) -> y.```name```)
````

but it gives me the following error:

> Unexpected reserved keyword in lambda expression. Expected incomplete
>   structured construct at or before this point or other token.

Simple invocation of function should look like this:

```
getValue(tuple, "a")
```

and it should be equivalent to the following function:

```
let getValue (tuple) =
        snd tuple |> Seq.averageBy (fun (y: CsvProvider<"s.csv">.Row) -> y.a)
```

Is something like this is even possible?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you'll need reflection for this - but why don't you use an getter instead of the name? `let getValue (ts, getter : CsvProvider<"s.csv">.Row -> 'a) = ...`

Comment: @Carsten yup I could, but I was thinking that I can do it like this, because for me it will look a quite better.
So I suppose I should write something like You propose or 

let getValue (tuple, name: string) =
    snd tuple |> Seq.averageBy (fun y -> typedefof<CsvProvider<"s.csv">.Row>.GetField(name).GetValue() :?> float)

Comment: it's up to you but given the choice *I* would never use magic strings or reflection when I can have compiler checked expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSV type provider is great if you are accessing data by column names statically, because you get nice auto-completion with type inference and checking.

However, for a dynamic access, it might be easier to use the underlying `CsvFile` (also a part of F# Data) directly, rather than using the type provider:

```
// Read the given file
let file = CsvFile.Load("c:/test.csv")

// Look at the parsed headers and find the index of column "A"
let aIdx = file.Headers.Value |> Seq.findIndex (fun k -> k = "A")

// Iterate over rows and print A values
for r in file.Rows do
  printfn "%A" (r.Item(aIdx))
```

The only unfortunate thing is that the items are accessed by index, so you need to build some lookup table if you want to easily access them by their name.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Yup it seems to be a little problem that if I use CsvFile, to get properties I must use index.. I was thinking that CSVProvider also provide directly such functionality but it seems not to (or not to right now). Although Your answer 'answers' my question, so I will accept it. Many thanks!